# Signal animation not working on jsFiddle

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate the following animation effect found at http://codepen.io/cayoub88/pen/DCemr on JsFiddle but have little success. Any reason why this is happening?

My fiddle can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/9pknjor8/

Code

```css
body {
  background: #428CD6;
}
.signal {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -15px 0 0 -15px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.1);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="signal"></div>
```

Comment: It works fine here, this should be a browser-specific problem

Comment: I tested it on IE10 and it is working without making any changes.

Comment: [Codepen uses Autoprefixer](http://blog.codepen.io/2014/03/28/new-feature-autoprefixer/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `webkit` `moz` etc for it to work on jsfiddle i don't thinks that is necessary in codepen (http://blog.codepen.io/2014/03/28/new-feature-autoprefixer/) thanks to @anpsmn i tried this and it works fine in my chrome http://jsfiddle.net/9pknjor8/2/

```
.signal {
border:3px solid #fff;
border-radius:30px;
height:30px;
left:50%;
margin:-15px 0 0 -15px;
opacity:0;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
width:30px;

-webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
0% {
  transform:scale(.1);
  opacity: 0.0;
}
50% {
  opacity:1;
}
100% {
  transform:scale(1.2);
  opacity:0;
}
```